# WP Сохранение новых значений массива в wp_postmeta

Tags: wordpress

Есть задача хранить значения списка ID зарегистрированных пользователей которым понравился пост. (*Если пользователю нравиться пост, он жмет кнопку которая добавляет его ID в ячейку БД, если её до этого не было там). Один и тот же пользователь должен иметь возможность только раз быть в этом массиве.

Понимаю, что это реализуется при помощи двух методов. [update_post_meta()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/update_post_meta) и [get_post_meta()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_post_meta)  Вопрос, как контролировать перезапись данных, а точнее $prev_value?

Код:

```
function addRatingForPost()
{

    if (empty($_POST['postId']) || !isset($_POST['currentUserId'])) wp_send_json(['error' => __('Wrong Data', 'users_rating')]);

    $post_id = (int)$_POST['postId']; // ID поста
    $current_user_id = (int)$_POST['currentUserId']; // ID пользователя которому понравился пост

    $data = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'positive_users_reaction', true );
    if( ! $data ){
        $data = [];
    }
    $data[] = $current_user_id;

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'positive_users_reaction', $data);
    
    wp_die();
}
```

Код записывает пользователей в объект, но как-то странно. После первого захода, в ячейку массива записало `a:1:{i:0;i:1;}` после второго пользователя с другим ID в ячейке уже было - `a:2:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:4;}` после третьего пользователя `a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:3;}` Может чего не понимаю, но это не очень похоже на стандартные объект php . Ещё не понятно как реализовывать проверку, что б туда не попадало повторное значение ID уже проголосовавшего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё верно - в метаданные записывается сериалиазованный массив (см. функцию php [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)). После третьего пользователя строка `a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:3;}` означает сериализованный массив из трёх элементов

```php
[
0 => 1,
1 => 4,
2 => 3
]
```

Для удаления повторяющихся значений массива надо использовать функцию `array_unique()`. Вот слегка изменённый ваш код:

```php
function addRatingForPost() {
    if ( empty( $_POST['postId'] ) || ! isset( $_POST['currentUserId'] ) ) {
        wp_send_json( [ 'error' => __( 'Wrong Data', 'users_rating' ) ] );
    }

    $post_id         = (int) $_POST['postId']; // ID поста
    $current_user_id = (int) $_POST['currentUserId']; // ID пользователя которому понравился пост

    $data = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'positive_users_reaction', true );

    if ( ! $data ) {
        $data = [];
    }

    $data[] = $current_user_id;
    $data   = array_unique( $data );

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'positive_users_reaction', $data );

    wp_die();
}
```